# I want to query a string(date) based on the format of the Date

Tags: sql

SQL Question

I have a field that is stored as a string that is currently holding dates,

This field should be stored as `yyyy/mm/dd` but
unfortunately a large number of data was entered as `mm/dd/yyyy`

I want to know if there is a way to query the field to find only the rows that are in the wrong format.

Comment: The best thing to do here is FIX the schema, because it really is **broken**. In other words, _**ALL**_ the rows are in the wrong format. If you want the system to provide tools to help you manage dates, you need to let the system know you're actually using dates.

Comment: Yes, you can use `LIKE` for this purpose. If your RDBMS supports regular expressions, you can use that feature as well.

Comment: Working with dates is highly dependent on the `DBMS` you are using, so it's better to tag your question with your `DBMS`. i.e. in `SQL Server` you can simply use the `ISDATE()` function but in `MySQL` you may perform a workaround to simulate that function.

Comment: How can you be sure some data wasn't entered as `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: unfortunately I have no control over the schema, this is a 3rd party DB and I am not allowed to alter the field def(s).  I can only work with what I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most RDBMS offer some sort of *substring* function so given only your incorrect strings will have `/` at character position 3 you can simply say

```
where substring(Datecolumn,3,1) = '/';
```

Comment: This is actually what I went with, it was the quickest as easiest... Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the RDBMS but on SQL Server at least you could use this to get (only) the wrong format rows:

```
SELECT * FROM borkeddatestable WHERE datecolumnname LIKE '__/%'
```

Since the underscore - '_' is a single-character wildcard this will get you all rows where there's two characters followed by a '/'

Answer (score 1):

For pattern matching on a string you want to use a `LIKE` statement like shown bellow:

```
CREATE TABLE dates (dates VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO dates
VALUES  ('2022/01/02')
        ,('2022/02/27')
        ,('06/17/2022')
        ,('2022/03/12')
        ,('07/15/2022')
        ,('07/20/2022')
        ,('2022/04/02')

SELECT d.dates
FROM dates d
WHERE d.dates LIKE '__/__/____'
```

##### Resuts Table

| dates |
| --- |
| 06/17/2022 |
| 07/15/2022 |
| 07/20/2022 |

##### Update Incorrect Entries

```
UPDATE d
SET d.dates = RIGHT(d.dates, 4) + '/' + LEFT(d.dates, 2) + SUBSTRING(d.dates, 3, 3)
FROM dates d
WHERE d.dates LIKE '__/__/____'
```

**DB Fiddle:** [SQL Server Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=2fe7a01a878c13691ebe0164e31137b5)

Comment: This is excellent, and I will propose this as a solution.  To prevent them from wanting to reload all data since last May